# In Kotlin exception blocks, how does one implement an 'else' (success) block?

Tags: exception, kotlin

In Python, I would do this:

```
try:
    some_func()
except Exception:
    handle_error()
else:
    print("some_func was successful")
    do_something_else()  # exceptions not handled here, deliberately
finally:
    print("this will be printed in any case")
```

I find this very elegant to read; the `else` block will only be reached if no exception was thrown.

How does one do this in Kotlin? Am I supposed to declare a local variable and check that below the block?

```
try {
    some_func()
    // do_something_else() cannot be put here, because I don't want exceptions
    // to be handled the same as for the statement above.
} catch (e: Exception) {
    handle_error()
} finally {
    // reached in any case
}
// how to handle 'else' elegantly?
```

I found [Kotlin docs | Migrating from Python | Exceptions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/exceptions.html), but this does not cover the `else` block functionality as found in Python.

Comment: Just put it as a last line in the `try` block. and it will run if everything is ok

Comment: @Demigod Yeah, of course that works, but: 1) the exception handler than also handles the exceptions thrown form *that* statement, 2) it doesn't really read well in larger blocks. (I was hoping to have missed something simple from the Kotlin docs, but perhaps it's simply not there then.) **updated the question accordingly**

Comment: If some_func() is your own, it's probably worth rewriting it to not use an exception. As your code shows, handling them can be ugly and verbose. To quote the document you linked to "Note that exceptions are somewhat discouraged in Kotlin except when interacting with Java code. Instead of throwing exceptions in your own code, consider using special return types like Option or Either". Obviously if you are interacting with Java code, you don't have this choice :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way to use `runCatching` is to use the `Result`'s extension functions

```
runCatching {
    someFunc()
}.onFailure { error ->
    handleError(error)
}.onSuccess { someFuncReturnValue ->
    handleSuccess(someFuncReturnValue)
}.getOrDefault(defaultValue)
    .also { finalValue ->
        doFinalStuff(finalValue)
    }
```

Take a look at the docs for `Result`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html

Comment: also, note that because the "runCatching" is a "try and catch all exceptions"  in the failure case you should handle thrown exceptions properly and nut just swallow them

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the default value, for example, you want just to hide the loading you could use this:

```
runCatching {
    show_loading(true) //show loading indicator
    some_func() //this could throw an exception
}.onFailure {
    handle_error(it.message)
}.getOrNull().run {
    show_loading(false) //hide loading indicator regardless error or success
}
```